# Print all python logs within GitHub Action

Tags: python, github-actions

I have a GitHub Action that calls a python script:

```
- name: Test Python Script
  run: |
     python python_script.py
```

This runs fine and prints me the logs from within here:

```
if __name__ == "__ main __":
   print('Calling function')
   func_call()
   print('End of script')
```

However, I don't get the print statements from `func_call` itself:

```
def func_call() :
  print('inside func_call')
```

When I run from my own terminal, the output is:

```
Calling function
inside func_call
End of script
```

Yet when I run from a GitHub Action I only get:

```
Calling function
End of script
```

Is there a way I can propagate all print statements to the GitHub Action logs?

Comment: How is your `func_call` looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was relatively simple, just adding the `-u` flag:

```
- name: Test Python Script
  run: |
     python -u python_script.py
```

From `man python`:

```
 -u     Force stdin, stdout and stderr to  be  totally  unbuffered.   On systems  where  it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr in
binary mode.
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable.

```yaml
    env:
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: "1"
```